# MySQL COUNT query return total of values in rows

Tags: mysql

I have a guestbook, with messages stored in a table. There is a 'hits' field for each message. How do I run a query that will count the total number of hits?

```
SELECT name, COUNT(hits) FROM guestbook_message WHERE name='".$req_user_info['username']."' GROUP BY name";
```

This returns the amount of messages that the user has posted, where there is a value in the 'hits' field. But not the total amount of hits.

If there are 3 messages, with 3 hits each, it should return "9 hits". But the query I posted above would return "3".

Many thanks.

Comment: `COUNT` counts values. `SUM` adds values. [MySQL Aggregate Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're after `SUM`

```
SELECT name, SUM(hits) FROM guestbook_message WHERE name='".$req_user_info['username']."' GROUP BY name";
```

Answer (score 2):

You want SUM instead of COUNT.